# Accessing to columns in a grouped list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I made a `groupby` operation in a dataframe to group by the categorical value of an specific column. Something like:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df["categories"])
```

If I do `list(grouped)` what I get is a list of dataframes, one for each category. So far, so good.

But I want to select an specific column in each dataframe in the list. Imagine the column I want to access is named `vals`. I want something like:

```
my_array = [grouped[i]["vals"] for i in grouped]
```

But the previous command doesn't work, neither other combinations I have tried. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grouped` return `tuple`s - group name and `DataFrame`, so possible solution are:

```
#unpack tuples to i, df
my_array = [df['vals'] for i, df in grouped]
```

Or:

```
#select second value of tuple - df
my_array = [i[1]['vals'] for i in grouped]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'D':[1,3,5,7],
                   'vals':[5,3,6,9],
                   'categories':list('aabb')})

print (df)
   D categories  vals
0  1          a     5
1  3          a     3
2  5          b     6
3  7          b     9

grouped = df.groupby(df["categories"])

print (list(grouped))
[('a',    D categories  vals
0  1          a     5
1  3          a     3), ('b',    D categories  vals
2  5          b     6
3  7          b     9)]

my_array = [df['vals'] for i in grouped]
print (my_array)
[0    5
1    3
2    6
3    9
Name: vals, dtype: int64, 0    5
1    3
2    6
3    9
Name: vals, dtype: int64]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option seems to do what I want.

Comment: @David - Yes, it is my prefer way too, because nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've shared, it seems that you are using `i` as an index, which is incorrect. In your case `for i in grouped`, `i` is the actual object from the list.

**Try One of These**

`my_array = [df.vals for i, df in grouped]`

or

`my_array = [grouped[1][i]["vals"] for i in range(len(grouped))]`

Comment: Sorry, but your methods don't work. I think they fail due to the tuple structure of the list of a groupby, as @jezrael comments.

Comment: I misunderstood that`grouped` was just a list of list of dataframes. I've made edits that refer to grouped as a native Pandas DataFrameGroupBy object.